# List of Taxonomy terms from a list of nodes without duplicates

Tags: taxonomy, drupal-8

Is it possible to get the list of taxonomy terms in a field collection from a list of nodes using Views ?

At the moment in Views I can list the nodes from one Taxonomy term (in another vocabulary from the results I need). Each nodes have a field collection with taxonomy term. So I get something like that :

Term1 (Node1)
Term2 (Node1)

Term4 (Node2)
Term3 (Node2)

Term1 (Node3)
Term2 (Node3)
Term3 (Node3)

But I need to get the list with only one individual taxonomy term listed like this :

Term1
Term2
Term3
Term4

Any idea, with View ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out...

Don't put other field than the one you need.
In the field(s) you need, don't check "Multiple field settings" and each one will be treated independently.
In "Advanced", activate "Use aggregation".

In the end that solve the problem but it appears to be a dead end for the following of what I need to do. I had to code a custom block in my module to obtain exactly what I want in the end.